# Compute Engine - 1000 GB disk cant decrease size

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, disk-image

i have a huuuuge problem.

Created a snapshot and image from my instance...instance has 1000GB of disk.

Now i need to reduce it but everytime i try to create an image or a snapshot from that, i get the same error "Disk need to be at least 1000GB".

There is a way to reduce disk size directly on instance? Some workaround?

Comment: Google Cloud does not provide tools for resizing the file systems and partitions inside the snapshot. You can create a disk from the snapshot, use a third-party tool to resize and then copy the partitions to a smaller disk, then create a new snapshot. Another option is to create another disk, format and then copy the data from the exising disk to the new disk.

Answer (score 1):

> You can only resize a zonal persistent disk to increase its size. You
>   cannot reduce the size of a zonal persistent disk.

When storage parameters cannot be changed, create new storage. Get out and adapt a storage migration playbook.

One way to do so is with logical volumes. With Linux LVM:

- Make the LV fit the new size with `lvreduce --resizefs`
- Add a smaller disk with `vgextend`
- `pvmove` to the smaller disk
- `vgreduce` the old PV

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible to decrease the size of a Disk. You can only increment the size.

Source: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk